# Vue components displayed side by side despite each being se to 100% of window width

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue components have width set to 100vw each.Despite this,they still display side by side as if the `width:100vw` was ignored.I have screenshot of what the website looks like.All I want is the 2 components to be displayed as Form on top and Main right below.
[From component and Main component (both children of App component) are displayed side by side instead of Form on top and Main below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmxCp.jpg)

Form.vue

```
div
    {
        position:relative;
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        height:75vh;
    }

    form
    {
        margin-top:0;
        padding:8px 0;
        margin:5px;
    }
```

Main.vue

```
div
    {
        width:92.5%;
        position:static;
        height:auto;
        overflow:auto;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
```

I tried with every type of `position` but no change whatsoever.

Comment: their wrapper is most likely `display: flex` which causes that behavior

Comment: I generally say that don't use vw and vh as much as you can.

Comment: I always see conflicting advice on vw/vh and %.I use vw and vh because I always used viewport more than percentages (both are kinda the same-ish to me tho)